# Downloading CSV Returning is working fine with local API reference. With respect to Azure Server .Net core API throwing 502 bad gateway

Tags: .net-core, export-to-csv, .net-6.0, http-status-code-502

[image]

When I download CSV with Large Amount of data it working Fine. When I deploy to server it throwing 502 with in 20 Secs.

Even We have added command timeout for stored procedure and KeepAliveTimeout for kestrel